# Fundamental Theorem of Demography Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-modeling

How would you prove the limit in the following theorem? Here $x_k$ is a column vector.

> Let $P$ be a primitive projection matrix for a population model $x_k = Px_{k-1}$, with spectral radius $r$ and right and left eigenvectors $u$ and $v^T$ normalised so $v^Tu=1$. Then:
>   $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{x_k}{r^k} = (v^T x_0)u$$

I'm assuming it's through the use of the Perron-Frobenius theorem. We also have $x_k = P^kx_0$ if that helps.

Comment: I suppose this is a typo $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to\infty}\,\frac{x_k^{\color{red}k}}{r^k}$, right?

Comment: That would be correct, I have changed it @Batominnovski

Comment: Can you explain briefly what a primitive projection matrix is?  Does it have nonnegative entries, or strictly positive entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that a primitive projection matrix is just a [primitive matrix](https://planetmath.org/primitivematrix). 
 Since $P$ is a primitive matrix, the [Perron-Frobinius Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) applies.  That is, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\,\left(\frac{1}{r^k}\,P^k\right)=u\,v^\top\,.\tag{*}$$
Recall that $x_k=P^kx_0$ for every integer $k\geq 0$.  That is,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\,\left(\frac{1}{r^k}\,x_k\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\,\left(\frac{1}{r^k}\,P^kx_0\right)=\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\,\frac{1}{r^k}\,P^k\right)\,x_0\,.$$
From (*), we get
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\,\left(\frac{1}{r^k}\,x_k\right)=(u\,v^\top)\,x_0=u\,(v^\top\,x_0)\,.$$
Because $v^\top\,x_0$ is a scalar, we obtain
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\,\left(\frac{1}{r^k}\,x_k\right)=(v^\top\,x_0)\,u\,.$$